# what is the need of Context in a class default constructor when extends SQLiteOpenHelper??

Tags: android, sqlite

What is the need of Context in this class.Is there any backgroud work/process it does to identify the application?

```
class MyDatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
         public MyDatabaseHandler(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It uses the context to create a db file in the application folder. It requires context to find that folder

Answer (score 2):

The `Context` is required for accesing your application's data directory where the database files are stored.

It is not used yet in constuctor but later when the database is opened with e.g. a call to `getWritableDatabase()`.

For questions like these the answer is right there in the [source](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java#191).